# Как поменять версию php для apache в isp manager

Tags: ispmanager

В настройках в isp manager
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А в настройках php
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
php -i

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в apache поменять версию php на 7.2? хотя бы на 7.1

Из прочитанного понял, что нужно сделать версию 7.2 нативной, как это сделать?

Для чего это нужно: это нужно для работы с laravel, минимальная версия PHP 7.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел выход через Shell-клиент(Терминал)

`add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` - Добавляем репозиторий, если его нет

`apt-get update` - Обновляем

`apt-get install php7.1` - Устанавливаем новую версию

[Статья](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-php-7-1-6-on-ubuntu-17-04/)